# Difference between riak search mongodb indexing

Tags: mongodb, riak

So Riak launched Riak Search a while ago and introduced it into the core recently. Have not had a chance to play around with it, but was curious if people had a sense of how it compared to mongodb, the indexing and query capability that it provides?

Discussions about consistency, availability and others put aside, i am just looking to see pros and cons of riak search and mongodb query and indexing. Are each of them interchangeable all other things being the same?

Answer (score 1):

one distinct difference i noticed was:

mongodb can perform indexing on demand, If we enter 100 million records and then realize we have to add a new index, on a field that was previously unindexed, then we can. In the case of riak search(and i believe ), we will have to add the index, then reinsert all the k/v pairs.